# Adjusting text in tkinter Label to occupy all available space

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout, tkinter-text

Hy, I hope you are all doing well. I am building a Eye chart software in python tkinter which consists of Opto Charts.
In Opto Charts all alphabet comes directly below each other. But when I try to add labels in tkinter, it forms V shape as with each row font size is decreasing.
I want to occupy the label all the available space.

I managed to do that using  `mainFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` but it only makes the label to full width not the text inside it. I have attached a screenshot for how it looks.
[image]
In the screenshot you can see the labels are set to full length of screen but text is in V shape as font size is decreasing from top to bottom.
Is there a way to anchor the text to full width also. In others words each alphabet should come directly below the above one.

I hope I was clear, If you need to know anything else let me know.

Comment: try ```sticky='nsew'```

Comment: You would need a grid of individual letters to get the desired results.

Comment: @jasonharper yes that could be a possible solution but the solution presented by Jason Yang is much cleaner.

Comment: @Sujay doesn't make a difference. Anyway thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If an image or bitmap is being displayed in the label then the value is in screen units; for text it is in characters.

To occupy same space for different size of font, try to use image mode and use an empty image.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font

texts = ('EDFHT', 'FPYUI', 'TOZQW', 'LPEDA', 'PECFD')
sizes = (28, 24, 20, 16, 12)

root = tk.Tk()

factor = 2
tkfont = Font(font=("Courier New", max(sizes), 'bold'))
width, height = tkfont.measure("W")*factor, tkfont.metrics("linespace")*factor
image = tk.PhotoImage(data='')

for row, (text, size) in enumerate(zip(texts, sizes)):
    for column, t in enumerate(text):
        label = tk.Label(root, text=t, font=("Courier New", size, 'bold'), image=image, width=width, height=height, compound=tk.CENTER)
        label.grid(row=row, column=column)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your method works perfectly for my problem. There are a few of new things for me to get over in your code that I never new existed in tkinter.